# Consulta a mysql concat_ws

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Buenas soy nuevo en Java, mysql y estoy haciendo un programa y lo que quiero es concatenar dos campos de una tabla de mysql  y mostrarlo en una columna de un jtable…pero resulta que mi tabla(personal) mysql tiene 31 campos pero solo necesito 3 de ellos… nombres, apellidos y DNI; y mostrarlos en un jtable solo en 2 columnas(DNI | nombres y apellidos), la tabla carga bien solo que me carga DNI, nombres(no carga apellidos)

Explico lo que tengo de codigo..
Una clase datos donde se hacen las consultas sql, aquí tengo la consulta para el jtable del form..

```
Public ResultSet getPersonal(){
    Try{
        String sql=”select * from personal”;
        PreparedStatenent pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        Return pst.excecutequery(sql);
    }catch(…){
    ……
    }
}
```

El form donde está el jtable tiene el código siguiente

```
Private void llenarTabla(){
    String titulos []= {“dni”,”nombres y apellidos”};
    String registros [] =new String [2];
    miTabla = new DefaultTableModel (null, titulos);

    ResultSet rs= misDatos.getPersonal();

    While(rs.next()){
        registros[0]= “”+ rs.getInt(“dni”);
        registros[1]= rs.getstring(” “); // aquí en donde quiero que aparezca nombres y apellidos…
    }
}
```

Espero se entienda mi problema/consulta
Nose como armar la consulta sql  !!!!!!
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías probar cambiando tu sentencia SQL de

```
select * from personal
```

por:

```
select dni, CONCAT(nombres, ' ' ,apellidos) AS nombre_completo from personal
```

esto te devuelve únicamente los datos que necesitas y los puedes agregar a tus estructuras de datos que requieres.

Comment: Excelente.. arroja el resultado esperado..muchas gracias!